# MongoDB Atlas API: Create New CustomRole With Curl and Payload

Tags: mongodb, curl

I am having issues creating `customRoles` in MongoDB Atlas using API and curl.

Resource - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api-resources-spec/v2/#tag/Custom-Database-Roles/operation/listCustomDatabaseRoles

I can display `customRoles` created in MongoDB Atlas UI like this:

```
curl --user "{username}:{password}"  --digest --header "Accept: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json" https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/{groupID}/customDBRoles/roles
```

I am able to get

```
[{"actions":[{"action":"COLL_MOD","resources":[{"collection":"","db":"example"}]}],"inheritedRoles":[],"roleName":"callmodRole"},{"actions":[{"action":"COLL_MOD","resources":[{"collection":"","db":"example-logs"}]}],"inheritedRoles":[],"roleName":"customcallmodRole"}]
```

I am also able to delete

```
curl -v -X DELETE https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/{groupID}/customDBRoles/roles/customremoveRole --user "{username}:{password}"  --digest --header "Accept: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json"
```

The issue is I am unable to create `customRoles` in MongoDB Atlas with this curl command.

```
>curl -v -X POST https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/{groupID/customDBRoles/roles --user "{username}:{password}"  --digest --header "Accept: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json" -d {"actions":[{"action":"REMOVE","resources":[{"collection":"","db":"ambience"}]}],"inheritedRoles":[],"roleName":"customremoveRole"}
```

I got this error

> "error" : 415,
> "reason" : "Unsupported Media Type"

If I change the `--header` to `"Content-Type: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json"` or `"Content-Type: application/json"`

I'll receive

> {"detail":"Invalid accept header or version date.","error":406,"errorCode":"INVALID_VERSION_DATE","parameters":[],"reason":"Not Acceptable"}* Connection #0 to host cloud.mongodb.com left intact

Please do share where did I go wrong?

Updated.

I recently tried this but comes back with a different error

```
curl -v -X POST https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/{groupID}/customDBRoles/roles --user "{username}:{password}" --digest --header "Accept: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json" --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json" --data '{"actions":[{"action":"REMOVE","resources":[{"collection":"","db":"ambience"}]}],"inheritedRoles":[],"roleName":"customremoveRole"}'
```

The error is:

> {"detail":"Received JSON is malformed.","error":400,"errorCode":"MALFORMED_JSON","parameters":[],"reason":"Bad Request"}* Connection #0 to host cloud.mongodb.com left intact